# How could I get the desired output?

Tags: perl

```
System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 3

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = Sample
 Database name                        = sample
 Local database directory             = /home/db2inst1
 Database release level               = b.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Database 2 entry:

 Database alias                       = sample2
 Database name                        = sample2
 Local database directory             = /home/db2inst1
 Database release level               = b.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Database 3 entry:

 Database alias                       = sample3
 Database name                        = sample
 Local database directory             = /home/db2inst1
 Database release level               = b.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

I have this following text when I execute a system command. I want only `sample,sample2,sample3` as output. I'm familiar with doing this in shell, but I'm new to perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-n` option in a one-liner to handle stdin sent through a pipe:

```
yourcommand | perl -F'\s*=\s*' -anlwe '/Database alias/ && print $F[1]'
```

This is simply a split (`-a`) on the regex `/\s*=\s*/` which will split on equal sign and strip surrounding whitespace. When the target text is found, it prints the second field, which should be your string.

Comment: Wow i got it , Thanks a lot man @TLP , i just want to know how do we embed in the script as this is a command line things , above that where can i find some example for these kind of text processing stuff

Comment: "The script"? What script is that? If you want, run this with the `-MO=Deparse` switch to see the full code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is only slight modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953565/how-to-get-only-the-3rd-column/16717044#16717044). Basically, you want the fourth column of each line that starts with "Database alias". You can use perl `grep` function to select matching lines and then perform the selection from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953565/how-to-get-only-the-3rd-column/16717044#16717044) mentioned above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;
my @aliases;

open FILE, $file or die "Cannot open input file";

chomp (my @lines = grep /^Database alias/, <FILE>);    

close FILE;

for my $row (@lines) {                
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $row;  
    push @aliases, $columns[3];
}

print join "\n", @aliases;
```

If your input file is big, I recommend to go through the file using a `while` loop and filter out non-matching lines on-the-fly. Such approach would not store the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell commands in open like this:

```
open(IN,"cmd_that_generate_the_output|grep -i 'Database alias'|cut -f2 -d'='|cut -f2 -d' '|") or die;
while (my $str = <IN>){
  print "str: $str\n";
}
```

Comment: I am comfortable with the shell , in fact this is a script already running in our prod servers without any problem , all i am learning how do i do things in Perl staying out of shell native commands. thanks for your time , i appreciate it