# How to get only the 3rd column?

Tags: perl

I have an array @foo which has the entries like

```
 Database alias                       = SAMPLE1
 Database alias                       = SAMPLE2
 Database alias                       = SAMPLE3
```

Now i want only the 3rd column i.e

> SAMPLE1
>
> SAMPLE2
>
> SAMPLE3

I can do it in shell with `awk (awk '{print $3}')` , How do i do it in perl?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952014/how-could-i-get-the-desired-output ? I assume it is about parsing the same input. This exact question is answered in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: maybe mViswa needs to ask a different question if they aren't getting the answers they want

Comment: The third column is `=`!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $3}' < data.txt
```

gives = signs, you mean $4

In perl however, the autosplit array starts at zero so it is 3

```
perl -lane 'print $F[3]' < data.txt
```

Comment: my @foo=grep(/Database alias/,`db2 "list db directory"`); which gave me the O/p show in the above format , now im doing print "$foo[2]"; which is giving me "Database alias  = SAMPLE3" instead of expected

Answer (score 1):

If you want n-th column of whitespace-separated string, this is the idea how to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @foo = ( "Col1    Col2  Col3     Col4",     # This is
            "Row2    R2C2  Row2C3   Row2C4" ); # the input array.

my $n = 2; # We want to select the 3rd column.

my @nth_columns;

for my $row (@foo) {                   # We go through the input array,
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $row;   # splitting each row by whitespaces
    push @nth_columns, $columns[$n];   # and adding the n-th column to output array
}
```

You can of course write that in many shorter ways. My favourite would look like this:

```
my @third_columns = map { (split /\s+/)[2] } @foo;
```